# Applifier Impact Unity3d Android Video cancel crash

Tags: java, android, video, plugins, unity-game-engine

I've integrated successfully applifier sdk for unity Android and I found this crash very often in my live version. Any idea about this!

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version : 4.3.4f1
Device model : samsung GT-S7582

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.applifier.impact.android.view.ApplifierImpactMainView.onVideoPlaybackError(ApplifierImpactMainView.java:323)
at com.applifier.impact.android.video.ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView.videoErrorOperations(ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView.java:202)
at com.applifier.impact.android.video.ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView.access$12(ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView.java:198)
at com.applifier.impact.android.video.ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView$VideoStateChecker$5.run(ApplifierImpactVideoPlayView.java:706)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That looks like an error in Applifier itself; have you contacted their support about this issue?

Comment: Yes they fixed in latest update!